# QUERY using table valued functions in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION tedata 
    (@teacher_name[nchar] NOT NULL)
RETURNS @st TABLE 
            ([stu_id] [int] NOT NULL,
             [stu_nam] [varchar](255) NULL,
             [stu_dob] [date] NULL,
             [stu_add] [varchar](255) NULL,
             [org] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
             [org_id] [char](10) NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @teacher_id [nvarchar] NOT NULL

    INSERT INTO @st
        SELECT stu_id = @teacher_id
        FROM dbo.[teacher];

    RETURN 
END
GO
```

ERROR:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure tedata, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 20]
>   Incorrect syntax near 'NOT'.

I am getting the above error.

Comment: You *really* want to include a length with your character types. Not specifying one and getting the "default" (which may be 1, 30, or God knows what else) is a [bad habit](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR / NCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use - otherwise, it'll default to a length of **1 character** .....

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition is the problem:

```
CREATE FUNCTION tedata 
   (@teacher_name[nchar]  >>NOT NULL<<)
```

Not Null is not a valid modifier for a function parameter. Remove that, and your function should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted makes no sense. I "think" this is what you're after...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tedata
(
    @teacher_name NVARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
    SELECT 
        t.stu_id,
        t.stu_man,
        t.stu_dob,
        t.stu_add,
        t.org,
        t.org_id
    FROM
        dbo.teacher t
    WHERE 
        t.teacher_name = @teacher_name;
GO
```